# MySQL query will SUM but if statement in other field

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble with a mysql query, I want to select SUM with else if statement, this is my story.

My query:

```
SELECT SUM(s.total_revenue) AS sum_revenue, m.revenue_type AS revenue_type, d.campaignid AS placement_id
FROM ox_data_summary_ad_hourly AS s
INNER JOIN ox_banners AS d ON (d.bannerid = s.ad_id) 
INNER JOIN ox_campaigns AS m ON (m.campaignid = d.campaignid) 
INNER JOIN ox_clients AS a ON (a.clientid = m.clientid) 
WHERE a.type = 0
GROUP BY placement_id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

And query in above get result as below:

[image]

I want to generate query which:
If revenue_type=4 will change in value sum_revenue = value placement_id, 
Example result I want to as  image below:

[image]

Thanks for help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression to get the result:

```
SELECT 
    case 
        when m.revenue_type = 4 
        then d.campaignid 
        else SUM(s.total_revenue) end AS sum_revenue, 
    m.revenue_type AS revenue_type, 
    d.campaignid AS placement_id
FROM ox_data_summary_ad_hourly AS s
INNER JOIN ox_banners AS d 
    ON (d.bannerid = s.ad_id) 
INNER JOIN ox_campaigns AS m 
    ON (m.campaignid = d.campaignid) 
INNER JOIN ox_clients AS a 
    ON (a.clientid = m.clientid) 
WHERE a.type = 0
GROUP BY placement_id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT case when m.revenue_type = 4 then  d.campaignid else SUM(s.total_revenue) AS sum_revenue end, m.revenue_type AS revenue_type, d.campaignid AS placement_id
FROM ox_data_summary_ad_hourly AS s
INNER JOIN ox_banners AS d ON (d.bannerid = s.ad_id) 
INNER JOIN ox_campaigns AS m ON (m.campaignid = d.campaignid) 
INNER JOIN ox_clients AS a ON (a.clientid = m.clientid) 
WHERE a.type = 0
GROUP BY placement_id
LIMIT 0 , 30

Comment: Thanks solved too, But I using code from above, thanks for help me.

Comment: Sorry my code not formatted as i dont get any option on my iphone